# How can I debug mvc ajax calls effectively using the error function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am quite new to MVC, I had a function that I wrote to override the default event on a submit button and I would update a partial view based on the submit form.  It was working great.  Then it just stopped working.  The only thing I've changed is that I've added a few webshim things for a datepicker (IE 9). I tried commenting this out and nothing.  I placed an error function in the ajax call, and sure enough, the call is failing for some reason.  Below is my ajax call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DropDownForm").on("submit", function (event) {
            //Prevent default action on the drop down submit form
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var Project = $('#ProjectDropDown').val();
            var Release = $('#ReleaseDropDown').val();
            //Instead run this function - find Release and update table
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr("action"),
                //async: false,
                method: form.attr("method"),
                data: form.serialize(),
                error: function (exception) { alert(exception + "\n" + form.serialize() + "\n" + form.attr("action") + "\n" + form.attr("method")) }
            })
            .done(function (result) {
                $("#ReleaseTableBodyForm").empty();
                $("#ReleaseTableBodyForm").html(result +
                    '<br/><div><button style=\"text-align:center\">Submit</button></div>');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The form it is referencing:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoadRelease", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "DropDownForm", style = "" }))
{
    @*Dropdowns*@
    <select id="BusinessAreaDropDown" name="BusinessArea" onchange="javascript: FillGenericProject(); FillProject(); FillReleases();" style="width: 11em;">
        @Html.Partial(@"Dropdowns\_BusinessArea", Model.ProjectViewModels);
    </select>
    <select id="GenericProjectDropDown" name="GenericProject" onchange="javascript: FillProject(); FillReleases();" style="width: 11em;"></select>
    <select id="ProjectDropDown" name="Project" style="width: 18em;" onchange="javascript: FillReleases();"></select>
    <select id="ReleaseDropDown" name="Release" style="width: 11em;"></select>
    <button type="submit" id="GoButton" style="visibility:hidden;">Go</button>
}
```

And the controller that it was calling very happily until recently (In HomeController.cs)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadRelease(string Project, string Release)
    {
        var ProjectID = _ProblemReportsDB.ProjectMaps
             .Where(r => r.Project == Project)
             .Select(r => r.ID).FirstOrDefault();

        ViewBag.Project = Project;

        var Releases = from row in _ProblemReportsDB.PlannedOpenCloses
                       where (row.Project == ProjectID && (Release == null || row.Release == Release))
                       select row;

        return PartialView("_TableBody", Releases.ToList());
    }
```

I just have no idea how to debug the ajax call.

The error call is outputting this:

```
[object Object]
BusinessArea=Test1&GenericProject=Test2&Project=Test3&Release=Create+New+Release
/Home/LoadRelease
post
```

All of which is correct.  Just simply fails.  Is there some way I can get more information from the ajax error parameters?  [object Object] is kind of useless to me.

Comment: Not sure, but have you also changed the return type? if I'm not wrong it should be return Json(Releases.ToList());

Comment: @LiranBo The return type can also be html, I can specify html as the datatype, but it still fails.  It's not even attempting to run the C# function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way I can get more information from the ajax error
>   parameters? [object Object] is kind of useless to me.

As per the documentation for [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> error Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String
>   errorThrown )
>
> Function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
>   XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that
>   occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible
>   values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error",
>   "abort", and "parsererror".
>
> When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown
>   receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found"
>   or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can
>   accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.
>   Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and
>   cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

So the [object] you're getting is the `jpXHR` which is the jquery wrapper for the underlying `XMLHttpRequest`. If you want status text and error message, then add the additional parameters to your error callback:

```
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
      console.error(textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown); 
}
```

`Javascript` is not like `C#` in this respect. All arguments are essentially optional and you can also pass more arguments than a function signature requires.

Comment: Hurray, the error is "error: Internal Server Error" :( Back to debugging... You did answer the question though haha thanks